# Redux Saga VS Smart Component

Tags: redux

Вопрос касается реализации функционала и даже больше архитектуры.
Допустим мы храним некую информацию о пользователе в `cookie`. Вопрос, кто должен работать с этой `cookie`?

Вариант 1:
Работает middleware (saga), читает ее и вызывает действие, которое перенесет данные в store и сохраняет данные из store в `cookie`.

Вариант 2:
Сам умный компонент, читает и записывает `cookie` без использования `redux`.

Что предпочесть, "какие" за и "против"?

Comment: Первое, это часть более общего вопроса, нужно ли вам конкретное состояние в общем redux стейте или вы хотите из каких-то соображений совать его в internal state? Засовывая в internal state вы теряете машину времени по этому состоянию и прочие преимущества redux хранилища, зато так попроще и иногда оправдано

Comment: Второе, у вас умный компонент сразу начинает много знать о хранилище. И перенести тот или иной флажок из куки скажем в локалсторадж становится посложнее.

Comment: Ну то есть если делать "по феншую" то через мидлварь конечно, но не всегда имеет смысл делать по феншую)